# phpmysql - What data type to store time & status in 1 column using mysql?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Helo guys I have sample data like this table [image: Sprint Table]

What is the best data type to store for the time? On the time column I need to be able to store a term like DQ, DNS, and DNF.

NB: (DQ=Disqualified, DNS=did not start, DNF=did not finish)

Comment: I'd consider having an events table and then an event_results table. Every event_results record would have a link back to events and you would have columns like lane_number, time, results, etc in event_results. For your time column, it looks like it's in minutes currently? Consider storing it in seconds and then you could store it as a float.

Comment: @Brayden i tried to design like your suggestion. What I am really worried is the datatype to store time. As you can see, time should be able to store DNS, DQ, and DMS and it should be varchar, but I need to store it as time as well if participant finish the race should be store time record.

Comment: Are you against having that result-y data in a separate column? Why do you want both of those pieces of information in one column?

Comment: @Brayden when storing I split it into 2 table. But for view or edit operation i need to show it like the table

Comment: Ok so you agree time and results should be stored as two separate columns? I'd store time as seconds as a float and then you can format at the model level. In python, I'd do something like `str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=103.42))`

Comment: @Brayden if you store time as float? so string can be store as float as well? I mean how do you decode it to float to string / date again?

Comment: Well what kind of times are you working with? In your example, you have a time of `1.43.42`...what does that mean?

Comment: @Brayden 1:43:42 is time if the participant finish the race. But i need to store store a term like DQ, DNS, and DNF. So far, I store it as time, but i want to store DQ, DNS, and DNF as well. because my column to store time is TIME datatype, thats why I asked what datatype that can be store both datatype? time and char

Comment: Got it. Are you against storing them in separate columns? I'd like to hear your argument for why you need to store those in the same column.

Comment: @Brayden yeah, i stored in 2 tables. i did not store it in the same column, i am asking what data type can be use to store both type? you said float, if i store it as float how do i decode it to string again to return the result

Comment: I'm saying store the time and result in two columns on the same table and you're saying you stored in two different tables. If you store it in seconds, you can figure out how to convert it to the format you need. eg `str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=103.42))` => `0:01:43.42`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I understand is, you want to change from storing them in separate tables, to one column in one table. Use VARCHAR. VARCHAR is meant to store all kinds of characters, not just letters. You cannot store letters in TIME or FLOAT column data types so if you must store them as one column in one table those are not options.

Comment: No sir, I want to keep them in separate tables, to view as one column in one table. But I need to store time and term like dq,dns,dnf in the same column like time. I cannot store dns to time column because the datatype is time

Comment: The datatype of the view table should be VARCHAR then. I don't know much about creating view tables but if the column in the view table must hold letters and numbers what I said before still applies to the view table column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = "{time:'9.41', status:'DQ'}";
```

You could store data like this, relying on JSON to store both the time & status in one column.

To create this from a PHP array of data (for example, if you wanted to extract current data, put it into JSON format, and update the existing data set), you can do this...

```
$array = array("Athlete 1"=>array("time"=>"9.41", "status"=>"DQ"),"Athlete 2"=>array("time"=>"0.00", "status"=>"DNS")); 
foreach($array as $athlete=>$data){
 $json = json_encode($data); // encode their specific data
 // insert json data string into athlete time/status cell 
}
```

or...

```
$array = array("time"=>"9.41", "status"=>"DQ");
$athleteJSON = json_encode($array); // get json string for just this one athlete
```

You would then pull this out of the database, and using PHP parse it...

```
$data = json_decode($json, true); 
$time = $data['time'];
$status = $data['status'];
```

Personally I think you should store the time in one column, and status in another. It makes more sense that way. If you can't do that, storing the data in JSON will allow your database to do what you want it to, and be usable by a ton of different languages that access that data.

Can also do...

```
$time = 9.41;
$status = "DQ";
$data = "$time|$status";
```

This becomes a string... "9.41|DQ"

Store that in the database, and then when you take it out...

```
$data = "9.41|DQ"; // (taken from database result)
list($time, $status) = explode("|", $data); // split time & status
// that's it, now you have time & status variables for that cell!
```

Also, here's some reasonable column ideas...

> ```
> id (auto increment, integer, primary key), 
> tournament (varchar 255), 
> event (int 11), 
> event_name (varchar 255), 
> heat (int 11), 
> heat_desc (varchar 255-male/female/etc), 
> athlete_name (varchar 50), 
> time (varchar 15) ~ so float can't mess up decimal places, 
> status (varchar 5 - for dq/dns/dnf), 
> lane (int 11)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use seconds or miliseconds...  then encode

```
DNS = nil 
DFN = 0xFFFFFFFF
DQ  = 0xFFFFFFFE
```

That way DNF and DQ sort out to the end...

You just need to be sure you don't convert those high values to times when doing your display.